# How to choose which answer to accept?

Tags: discussion, answers

I've been concerned about what answer to choose as accepted. I have asked two questions on Stack Overflow. On my second one, there are three answers, and I feel that one of them answers my question better than the others. However, I did not choose this answer. Someone else gave an answer that solved my entire problem, part of which was the question I originally asked. I chose that one, and completely rewrote the function to make it more efficient. I don't know if I made the right choice, and it's a big deal to me that whoever deserves credit gets it. So I guess my real question is this: Is it better to choose the most useful answer or the one that answers the question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Accept the answer that is most useful *to you*, regardless of how well it answers the question as originally stated. Upvote all helpful answers.

Comment: And what if all of them are completely useless? (in the asker’s subjective opinion, of course)

Comment: @Timwi Then don't accept any answer. That's why accept rates of 80% are still considered good — because there's no guarantee that the right answer will be there.

Comment: very good point! +1 =)