# How do I give an accepted answer to my question if I cannot tell which of 2 answers is correct

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What answer to accept?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28276/what-answer-to-accept)
>   [How to choose which answer to accept?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63821/how-to-choose-which-answer-to-accept)

Most of the time, Stack Exchange questions are fact based if they follow the format correctly and therefore it is quite easy to pick out the right answer.  This is especially true if someone gives me a few lines of code that I can easily verify on my own machine, or at least a jsfiddle site.  What should I do if I am unable to verify which of two differing answers is in fact the best one?  The way a particular question is answered one of them has to be right (to some degree) and one of them wrong.  My query here is meant to be answered for across sites and not necessarily specific to SO.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Maybe he needs a better way of arriving at the conclusion of which answer being the most useful (which can be quite subjective)

Answer (score 2):

Well you should give the best answer award to the answer that solved your problem, not the best looking/ longest/ neatest answer.

If many answers solve your problem, you can try to select based on two things:

1. Which answer do you want future users to see when they have a problem similar to yours? Just pick the answer that best explains the solution.
2. If all the answers look the same, try picking the answer that was posted first. You can see when the answer was posted right above their profile picture, to the bottom right of their answer.

Comment: Or just pick the answer of the newbie when the answers are the same.

Answer (score 0):

> **Accept the answer that is most useful to you**, regardless of how well it answers the question as originally stated. Upvote all helpful answers.

<sup>[Written by waiwai933](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63822/163863). Emphasized by me. <sup>So I take all the credit</sup></sup>

Comment: The most useful is the factually correct answer, but I am not in a position to state which it is because the 2 answers contradict each other.

Comment: @demongolem: In which case you should comment on the answers and ask them for each others opinion on each others answer.

Comment: How will you know if it's correct if you don't try to implement it?

Comment: Because it is on a StackExchange site that has nothing to do with computers. As there are more and more diverse StackExchange sites opened, some of the older, well-quoted answers may need to be thought through again.

Comment: @AlE: Might be difficult on [german.se] or other similar sites...

Comment: Ah. Good point.