# How do I accept an answer when more than one provided the solution?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to select the correct answer when their content is equal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125486/how-to-select-the-correct-answer-when-their-content-is-equal)

How do I accept an answer when two users provide a complete solution to a problem?

Case - [Image can not be displayed because it contains error in php gd](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14036298/1369235)

In this both [cryptic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14036319/1369235) and [user1711126](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14036498/1369235) helped me to solve the problem.

Comment: Also duplicate of: [Which answer do I accept if I have multiple correct answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13396/187824)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should accept the answer which is appropriate to us. If both are appropriate then accept the one which has more information and reference. If still both have equal quality then we should accept the oldest answer. But don't forget to upvote other same answer.

Answer (score 1):

in case more than one answer solve problem you can accept better one which provide also relevant information or good approach and there is still upvote ..so up vote other useful answer

Answer (score 1):

You should always select the best answer for accepted answer, and if you think both of them are equally good then you should give preference to the answer posted first. But if you think that both of the answers have given you the clue to solve your problem, then you may post your own answer with the complete solution, or if it only require a minor change you may request the answerer to modify his/her answer to reflect the change. Remember to vote up all the answers which were useful for you.